# Examples of locale-specific behaviour for Java BreakIterator's word and sentence splitters?

Tags: java, locale

Java's BreakIterator class allows one to split a sentence into characters, words, and sentences according to the rules of a given locale.  Can someone give me an example text string whose word and sentence boundaries are interpreted differently by BreakIterator in different locales?